# Where should I install the LESSPHP compiler?

Tags: theming

Hello I just bought a premium theme for Drupal. This theme works with the Less css preprocessor module, and I've installed and enabled this module:

[image]

The problem is, the site still doesn't look designed, and I get Drupal errors printed to the screen indicating on problems with Less. Thus I went to the themes' suport forum, ran a search and understood I need to download something called "LESSPHP" (A PHP based LESS-CSS comipler I guess) and install it somewhere in my Drupal installment, but I just don't know where and if it even a right step. Moreover, my site also indicated I miss this "LESSPHP" preprocessor at admin/config/development/less:

[image]

Where should I install this "LESSPHP" compiler and what else do you think I missed given the errors I see above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Less Processor Module](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php/archive/v1.7.0.5.zip) page it says:

> **Requirements**
>
> Libraries API
>
> less.php and unpack it so that
>   'lessc.inc.php' is located at
>   'sites/all/libraries/lessphp/lessc.inc.php'.

Which means:

1) you need to **download and enable** the [Libraires API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries)

2) Then you need to download [Less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php/releases/download/v1.7.0.5/less.php_1.7.0.5.zip) **<-- click here to download it**

3) Open the zip file, and grab the `lessc.inc.php` file only

4) Next you'll need to create some folders in your web directory **(create a libraries folder inside the all folder, and a lessphp folder inside the libraries folder)** so it looks like this

```
sites/all/libraries/lessphp/
```

5) **Upload** the `lessc.inc.php` file to the `lessphp` folder.